# How to create a responsive footer of 6 items with bootstrap 4.1.1?

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am not able to align this footer, I need the 6 items to stay in the footer and not be "cut" from the screen.

[image]

```
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-between justify-content-sm-around align-items-center w-100 mt-1">
                    <li class="nav-item text-center             "><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><img src="images/logotypes/aliansce-logo-icon.svg" class="mr-sm-2" alt="Aliansce Logo" width="25" height="25">SOBRE</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-chart-line     fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i>NÚMEROS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag   fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i>MARCAS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-camera         fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i>GALERIA</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fab fa-accusoft       fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i>PLANTA</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i>LOCAL</a></li>
                </ul>


<!-- INSERIR O CÓDIGO AQUI -->
```

Comment: Need not be "cut" from the screen - then what do you expect? Wrapped?

Comment: @David Liang 
In this template I'm using the bootstrap, but it has the same template in which I do not have access and the responsiveness of the flexs in the "hand" is made, and there it fit all 6 items ..

Comment: So you expect those 6 items will fit in a row even on the portrait mode of the phone, without wrapping?

Comment: @David Liang 
I agree with you about all theory of container responsiveness and etc ... But I myself saw this same template with the 6 items in portrait without breaking. That's why I came to ask how I can do this, because I can not do it.

Comment: It's so easy to achieve what you want with just `flexbox`. Do you have to use `bootstrap` css classes and its `navbar-nav` structure?

Comment: @David Liang, I tried to use the bootstrap "flexs" too but I did not get the effect, I'm using the boostrap by default of the project, but I just want to keep the 6 items aligned the way I said for smartphones. Would you help me?

Comment: Actually your layout and usage of bootstrap css classes work just fine. It's overflowing on portrait mode because it just doesn't have enough width.... You can set its parent `overflow-x: hidden;`, or decrease the font size, but other than that, there's nothing you can do since you don't want multiple rows appear.

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED THE PROBLEM OF THE FOLLOWING:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .footer-nav-title { font-size: 0.72rem; }
}


 <!-- FOOTER DE NAVEGAÇÃO -->
    <footer role="footer" class="navbar navbar-expand invisible-scrollbar fixed-bottom al-bg-dark-grey">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-start justify-content-sm-around align-items-center w-100">
                <li class="nav-item text-center             "><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><img src="images/logotypes/aliansce-logo-icon.svg" class="mr-sm-2" alt="Aliansce Logo" width="25" height="25"><span class="footer-nav-title">SOBRE</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-chart-line     fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i><span class="footer-nav-title">NÚMEROS</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag   fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i><span class="footer-nav-title">MARCAS</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-camera         fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i><span class="footer-nav-title">GALERIA</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fab fa-accusoft       fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i><span class="footer-nav-title">PLANTA</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center mt-1 mt-sm-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg mr-sm-2 al-text-green"></i><span class="footer-nav-title">LOCAL</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
```